# Field mailSender in com.example.demo.EmailService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, dependencies, spring-boot-test

This is a spring Boot project for sending emails, I've followed various tutorials and they all lead me to this configuration, unfortunately it doesn't work.
The program gives me the following error:

```
Description:

Field mailSender in it.trefin.asmar.ws.asmarWS.service.EmailService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' in your configuration.
```

In my pom I added JavaMailSender dependency

Main

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class EmailSenderController {
    
    @Autowired
    EmailService emailService;
    
    @PostMapping("/sendEmail")
    public String sendEmail() {
        emailService.sendEmail("rosaria.capuano.ext@3fedin.it", "Prova email", "Tieni duro");
        return "Messaggio inviato";
    }

}
```

The service

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class EmailService {
        
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String body) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);

        mailSender.send(message);
    }
    
}
```

My application.properties

```
#EmailSender Configuration
spring.mail.host=smto.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username="myemail"
spring.mail.password="myPassword"
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

What should I do?

I don't know what to change at all

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss the dependency which contains the mentioned class.

Add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom

Comment: I already had the addiction